# Changing text alignment with page size bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs centred side-by-side using bootstrap. One div is `text-right` aligned and the other `text-left`. I'm trying to get it so that these become centred on top of each other when the page becomes to small to view them side by side. I have tried using `@media` rule in CSS to deal with this but with no luck. Any suggestions? The HTML so far looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 text-right">
        <p class="summary">Some summary text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
        <p class="description">An extended description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE!

The CSS relating to the two divs:

```
/* Summary text */
.summary {
    font-family: 'Stint Ultra Expanded', cursive;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
/* Description text */
.description {
    font-family: 'Slabo 13px', serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .summary,
    .description {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your `@media` CSS.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Edited my question to include the CSS.

Comment: If you are testing on mobile, are you sure the screen size you are testing on is under 300px wide? If not, that may be why you are seeing it not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

300px max width is far too smaller to trigger.  If you're using `.col-md-3` then the two columns will occupy the full screen width starting at `992px` and lower.  See the [Bootstrap Docs on Media Queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .summary,
    .description {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 text-right">
        <p class="summary">Some summary text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
        <p class="description">An extended description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to go even smaller than 992px, you can use `.col-sm-3` or `.col-xs-3` or even come up with your own custom column widths by wrapping them in a media query.

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to your columns as this will be more specific in your css and overwrite the Bootstrap css.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="column-one" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 text-right">
        <p>Some summary text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="column-two class="col-md-3 text-left">
        <p>An extended description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #column-one, #column-two {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```